# Specify if image of url leads to null

Tags: javascript, php, image, error-handling

I am designing a site that displays the icon of any song, on the server. I have created a php file that returns the image of the song, if it exists. My code in HTML:

```
<img src="/image.php?song=SongName" width="100" height="100">
```

If the given song has a cover icon, then the img element shows the icon. If it doesn't, I get an empty 100x100 img box.

Now, I want to specify in javascript, if the url address: '/image.php?song=SongName' returns null (if there is not an image cover on the song), in order to hide the img. How to achieve it?

Thanks.

PS. The code I've tried so far (there's a bit of php for the img url formation):

```
var picElement = document.getElementById("picture");
picElement.src = "/image.php?song=$nameFile";
if(picElement.src == null){
    picElement.style.display = "none";
}else if(picElement.src !=null){
    picElement.src = "/image.php?song=$nameFile";
    picElement.style.height = "20vh";
    picElement.style.width = "20vh";
    picElement.style["boxShadow"] = "3px 3px 10px 1px #e2b674";
}
```

The php code under image.php:

```
<?PHP
$song= $_GET["song"];
require_once("getID3-1.9.15/getid3/getid3.php");
$Path= .$song.".mp3";

$getID3 = new getID3;
$OldThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($Path);
if(isset($OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]))
{
    header('Content-Type: ' . $OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]['image_mime']);
    echo $OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]['data'];
    die;
}?>
```

Comment: So it returns an error? Than use onerror

Comment: How have you tried to solve this yourself?  Do you have sample code?

Comment: If the image does not exist, I would expect it to be a 404 and than the onerror handler can set the image path to another image src. If you are just returning a blank image, you are making it a lot harder to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to handle displaying the default image using only markup, you can add an attribute [`onerror="this.src='/image.php?song=Default'"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) or similar to each image:

```
<img src="/image.php?song=SongName" onerror="this.src='/image.php?song=Default'" width="100" height="100"/>
```

This assumes that `/image.php` will properly return a 404 error when an image is not found, rather than displaying a default image itself.

#### Update

Following your PHP code, you might want to just echo the song name to HTML instead of to JavaScript:

```
<img src="/image.php?song=<?PHP echo $nameFile; ?>" onerror="this.style.display='none'" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But why onerror event is triggered?

Comment: @Nick because your `/image.php` does not return image data when `if(isset($OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]))` is false